# UI Redress and automated clicking

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

There is one thing I don't understand about the UI Redressing attack. Basically what I understand is:

1- The user clicks on a external URL

2- The attackers webpage opens. Inside this webpage, the original webpage is loaded as an iframe in a transparent manner.

3- As the user interacts with the attackers webpage he will actually be interacting with the transparent iframe.

Here is where I am confused. Why does the user even need to interact with the loaded webpage? Once the inner iframe is loaded you can have a javascript code to automate clicks on the page. Since this is all happening on the victims browser the target site will receive the victims session cookie and assume everythings fine.

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance

Note: Please note this is a UI Redressing attack also known as click-jacking. This is different than phishing attacks.

Answer (score 0):

The user *wants* to interact with the loaded webpage, because the user is not aware they are visiting a fake (inauthentic) page.  I'm not 100% certain about the javascript, but I'm pretty sure the attacker wants to log the user's activity (e.g, keystrokes for a password).

Comment: I think your mixing this with a phishing attack. This is a UI Redressing attack.